# Smooth view area transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, jquery-animate

as you can see in this JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/EychPixels/pABPv/1/ , when you move the character using the arrow keys until the view area moves with it, the character seems to move back 1 tile then forth 1 tile. Is there a way to fix this like animating the view area with the character? For animating the character I used `.animate` with jQuery, is it possible to do the same thing with the view area? If so can I see an example of this using my code?

If you need any more detail to answer the question just ask.

Comment: No character image is showing.

Comment: I will quickly fix that

Comment: @jimjimmy1995 the character has been fixed http://jsfiddle.net/EychPixels/pABPv/1/

Comment: You basically need to move the world instead of the character.

Comment: @jimjimmy1995 how would I go about doing that?

Comment: You need to apply the negative of what you did to the player so if you do `player.x--` you need to do `world.x++`. Of course when you get to the edge of the world you will have to switch back to moving the player as the world cannot move anymore.

Comment: @jimjimmy1995 alright thanks I will try that out!

Comment: You should also catch the keyboard input with separate if statements rather than a switch which will allow diagonal movement.

Comment: @jimjimmy1995 Sorry, I am having troubles trying to move the view area rather than the player could I get an example using my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your current code, the path of least resistance (i.e. the way that will need to change less code) would be to pass `now` to the draw function during an animation, if the viewport should animate too. Then you can follow @jimjimmy1995's suggestion (undoing the `player.x` change and doing an opposite `world.x` change).

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/pABPv/3/) offers a crude example (only for the "down" key). Details:

1. Determine whether or not the viewport will move during the animation:

   ```
      var move = Math.round(playerY+1) - Math.floor(0.5 * vHeight) > vY;
   ```
2. Pass the `now` function to `draw` (only if the viewport will move):

   ```
           step: function(now) {
              playerY = now;
               draw(move ? now-start : 0);
           }
   ```
3. In the `draw` adjust the viewport and player positions:

   ```
   function draw(now) {
       if ( !now )
           now = 0;
       ...
               theY = (y-now) * 32;
       ...
       context.fillRect((playerX-vX)*32, (playerY-vY-now)*32, 32, 32);
   ```
4. Draw an "extra" tile, to compensate for the blank space (not implemented in the example);
5. When the animation ends, draw it again, with `now == 0` (not implemented in the example).

There are still a few glitches, but should serve as a base for future improvements.